Second derivative and inflection point
Let
$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\sin(\frac{1}{x})\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}},  & \text{if $x\neq0$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$
Does $f''(0)$ exist? Is $x_0=0$ inflection point?
Regarding the first part, do I have to check continuity of $f'$ in $x_0=0$ and if $\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}f''(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}f''(x)$? And I don't even know how to start the second part - should I find $f^{(4)}$? I don't think so...

An inflection point is a point where concavity switches. $f’’(0)=0$, but this is really not sufficient to tell you anything.

Since $\exp(-1/x^2)$ just completely bulldozes the other factors for $x \rightarrow 0$, $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ so that's not really helping.

then what should I do?

To answer the first part, it's pretty easy to check that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0-}f(x) = f(0) = \lim \limits_{x \to 0+}f(x)$ and because the localized area around $0$ acts linear you can treat the subsequent derivatives like they are $0$. Because of that, we can say that $f''(x)=0$, but because the surrounding points are also $0$, we can't say that it is an inflection point just like how the second derivative of a linear function or a constant also can't have an inflection point.
As for checking continuity, it's always best practice to at least try to if you can. And because you are checking a differentiable function around one point, the limits around that point will always equal each other: $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0-}f(x)  = \lim \limits_{x \to 0+}f(x) \mid \lim \limits_{x \to 0-}f'(x)  = \lim \limits_{x \to 0+}f'(x)\mid \lim \limits_{x \to 0-}f''(x)=\lim \limits_{x \to 0+}f''(x)\mid... $$
so it isn't necessary to hand check $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}f^{(4)}(x)$.If you want more information, you can check this page for the rules about integrating piecewise functions.
